# Function stopped working after Protractor PageObject implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I've got a problem with executing multiple tests(i've got two here). It seems like function `deleteOneTask()` stopped working and my tests started to fail each other. Before i started to use PageObject everything was ok.

```
Stacktrace:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at c:\Users\Денис\WebstormProjects\ProtractorTest\pages\angular.page.js:29:30
```

It refers to this line: `this.deleteButton.click();`

Here is my **spec.js**

```
'use strict';

var todoAppPage = require('../pages/angular.page');

describe('angularjs todo list', function () {

    var page;

    beforeEach(function () {
        page = new todoAppPage();
        page.get();
    });

    it('should add a todo task', function () {
        page.addNewTask('my first task');

        expect(page.todoList.count()).toEqual(1);
        expect(page.todoList.get(0).getText()).toEqual('my first task');
        page.deleteOneTask(); //here it won't work
    });

    it('should show correct number of undone tasks', function () {
        page.addNewTask('my first task');

        expect((page.counter).getText()).toEqual('1'); 
        page.deleteOneTask(); //here it won't work
    });

    it('should show correct number of undone tasks2', function () {
        var deleteButton = element.all(by.className('destroy')).get(0);
        var viewArea = element(by.model('todo.completed'));

        page.addNewTask('my first task');
        expect((page.counter).getText()).toEqual('1'); 

        element(by.id('footer')).element(by.linkText('All')).click();
        browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(viewArea).perform().then(function () { //hover and delete single task
        deleteButton.click();
    });; //here it will work
  });
});
```

Here is **Page Object** file

```
'use strict';

var todoAppPage = function() {

    this.newTodo = element(by.model('newTodo'));
    this.todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todos'));
    this.viewArea = element(by.model('todo.completed'));        
    this.deleteButton = element.all(by.className('destroy')).get(0);
    this.categoryAll = element(by.id('footer')).element(by.linkText('All'));
    this.counter = element(by.id('todo-count')).element(by.className('ng-binding'));

    this.get = function() {
        browser.get('#/');
    };

    this.addNewTask = function (taskName) {
        this.newTodo.sendKeys(taskName);
        this.newTodo.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
    };

    this.deleteOneTask = function () {
        this.categoryAll.click(); //go to 'All' category
        browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(this.viewArea).perform().then(function () { //hover and delete single task
        this.deleteButton.click();
    });
  };
};

module.exports = todoAppPage;
```

Comment: Nothing defines "categoryAll" on your todoAppPage.  (And "page.counter" looks unlikely to work, either).

Comment: what line is the error referring to ? can you post stack trace

Comment: i've added info to question

Comment: Problem was solved by adding `var _this = this;` to PageObject and replacement `this` in `deleteOneTask()` function:
  `_this.deleteButton.click();`. But I don't think it is the best way. Can anyone suggest smthng more elegant?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, using a `that = this` will solve your problem. Eg.

```
this.deleteOneTask = function () {
  var that = this;
  this.categoryAll.click(); //go to 'All' category
  browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(this.viewArea).perform().then(function () { //hover and delete single task
  that.deleteButton.click();
});
```

That's the best solution I've seen but I'd be happy to see a better one too.